# Rollback the edit made by someone else to my answer - Stack Overflow

Tags: support, edits, rollbacks

I have posted some answers and other people are editing the answers without my permission.

I know it is mostly helpful but in cases, my answers have become wrong.

So, I was thinking if there is any option where I can rollback the edit made by someone else to my question/answer.

[image]

The above edit, though, improved my answer. But the second edit was made by someone else, and as you can see, I am not having a rollback option for the same.

The link to the question is:
[Which kind of CSS adding so that header begins directly at beginning of page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59720972/which-kind-of-css-adding-so-that-header-begins-directly-at-beginning-of-page/59721022#59721022)

Comment: Just go to the edit history and you will find a rollback link next to previous versions

Comment: I checked. But if the changes are made by me, then I am able to see the rollback option. If the edit is made by someone else, then I am not able to see the rollback option. Does that option gets activated once you reach some particular reputation score?

Comment: You should always be able to see the rollback link. Can you take a screenshot of what you're seeing? Possibly there's a bug. Also, if you add a link to the answer(s) you need rolled back, maybe someone can do that for you in the meantime.

Comment: I have updated the question. Added the screenshot.

Comment: the rollback link you want to use is the one on your original post.  That will roll the answer back to the first version, the one you made.

Comment: Linking to the question helps us too; we can all view the revision history.

Comment: The "rollback" link exists on every version of the post, except the current version. You can "rollback" to the current version of the post (i.e. you can't replace the current version with itself).

Comment: SO, usually, has tooltips on buttons which provide more detailed information as to what the button does. If you're wondering what one does, it's a good idea to mouse-over the button to show the tooltip. The tooltip for the "rollback" button is: 'sets the current revision to this version of the post, resetting any "rude or abusive" flags'.

Comment: Seems the user in question made almost the exact same edit to both answers on the question

Comment: Side note: linking very low quality posts (like "try this"/"might work" one in this post) may cause meta-effect. Posting link to your own VLQ post is fine... be more careful if you want to link to someone else posts.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your rollback link *is* present:

[image: Right there]

The link is not "roll back this edit" but rollback *to this version*. The current version never has this link (as rolling back to the current version doesn't change anything).